# CKEditor 4: how to force the "framed" mode

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Automatically CKEditor uses the "inline" mode, while I would like to use the "framed" mode.

This happens in my case, even if reading the documentation does not seem normal, I'm probably doing something wrong.

I have a simple textarea, to which I also tried to add the `contenteditable` attribute, without any success.

```
<textarea name="text" class="form-control wysiwyg editor" id="text" rows="10" contenteditable="false"></textarea>
```

This is instead the code with which I initialize the editor:

```
$(function () {
    $('.editor.wysiwyg').each(function () {
       CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
        CKEDITOR.replace(this.id, {
            disableNativeSpellChecker: false,
            fontSize_sizes: '10/10px;11/11px;12/12px;14/14px;16/16px;18/18px;20/20px;22/22px;24/24px;26/26px;28/28px;30/30px;',
            height: 375,
            image2_alignClasses: [ 'float-left', 'text-center', 'float-right' ],
            insertpre_class: false,
            removeButtons: 'Font',
            removeDialogTabs: false,
            tabSpaces: 4,
            toolbarCanCollapse: true,
            toolbarGroups: [
                { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
                { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
                { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
                { name: 'links' },
                { name: 'insert' },
                { name: 'forms' },
                { name: 'tools' },
                { name: 'others' },
                '/',
                { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
                { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
                { name: 'styles' },
                { name: 'colors' },
                { name: 'about' }
            ],
        });
    });
});
```

I have read [this](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/dev_framed) and [this page](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/dev_inline) of the documentation, but I have not found anything useful.

I'm using the jQuery adapter.

How can I do? Thank you.

Comment: You don't need contenteditable attribute on textarea to use ckeditor. if ckeditor do not start without it, check your console on errors. Your run config looks fine.

Comment: @saz I'm sorry, but CKEditor starts, only that it starts in the "inline" mode and not in the "framed" mode. No errors on console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The problem was caused by the [divarea](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/divarea) plugin. Instead, we need to use the  [IFrame Editing Area](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/wysiwygarea)plugin.

In fact, in the plugin page it is explained that:

> This is the core functionality of the classic, iframe-based editor which can only be disabled if it is backfilled by an alternative plugin (such as Div Editing Area) or if only inline editor is used.

Too bad that this is not explained in the documentation (how to report it to who takes care of the documentation?).

So I make sure I have the right plugin, then I used the [removePlugins](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-removePlugins) config option to disable the `divarea` plugin.